# Excel VBA - Cycle through ListBox controls

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to cycle through a number of worksheets, then listbox controls within each worksheet and populate them with my code. I am using the code below:

```
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim obj As OLEObject
Dim lst As MSForms.ListBox
Dim idx As Long

For idx = 1 To ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(idx)
    For Each obj In sh.OLEObjects
        If obj.progID = "Forms.ListBox.1" Then
            Set lst = obj
            If (lst.Name = "lst1") Then
                Call PopulateSimple(lst, "Table1")
            End If
        End If
    Next
Next idx
```

This seems to fail unfortunately when I set the listbox to the object. Any idea as to how I can achieve looping through all the listboxes in different worksheets and then populating them?

Comment: What reference(s) do you require for this? `MSForms.ListBox` gives me a compile error, "User defined type not recognized"

Comment: Disregard, I found a reference to MS Forms library.  When I run this code, sh.OLEObjects is empty.  How have you inserted the ListBox control?

Comment: In my opinion you need to change `Dim lst as MSForms.ListBox` into `Dim lst as OLEObject` and that is all...

Comment: + 1 @KazJaw: Yup that is the problem. However we don't need `lst` at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim obj As OLEObject
    Dim idx As Long

    For idx = 1 To ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
        Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(idx)
        For Each obj In sh.OLEObjects
            If TypeOf obj.Object Is MSForms.ListBox Then
                If (obj.Name = "lst1") Then
                    Call PopulateSimple(obj, "Table1")
                End If
            End If
        Next
    Next idx
End Sub
```

**Explanation**: You are getting that error because obj is declared as `OLEObject` and lst as `MSForms.ListBox` and hence a type mismatch.

Comment: you beat me to it by about 3 seconds !

Comment: @Philip: Thanks Philip :) 3 Secs? 4 mins you mean? ;)

Answer (score 0):

can't you use the obj in your call to **PopulateSimplesince** you know it is a ListBox:

```
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim obj As OLEObject
Dim lst As MSForms.ListBox
Dim idx As Long

For idx = 1 To ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(idx)
    For Each obj In sh.OLEObjects
        If obj.progID = "Forms.ListBox.1" Then
            'Set lst = obj
            If (obj.Name = "lst1") Then
                Call PopulateSimple(obj, "Table1")
            End If
        End If
    Next
Next idx
```

Answer (score 0):

simplest way (moved from comment):

In my opinion you need to change

```
Dim lst as MSForms.ListBox
```

into

```
Dim lst as OLEObject
```

and that is all...