# How to create a loop on e.g.,. TextBoxes' name placed within the Worksheet in Excel?

Tags: vba, excel

I have TextBoxes on UserForm and in Excel File (unfortunately).
I can do the loop on those in UserForm, and it works perfectly:

```
Dim txt(1 To 20) As String
txt(3)=("txtCompany")
txt(4)=("txtDataSource")
....
For i = 1 To 20
If frmInfo.Controls(txt(i)).Value <>
Worksheets(SheetNameDataBaze).Cells(ERow, i).Value Then ....
```

However, there is a huge problem with controls placed on the worksheet.
I tried:

```
Worksheets(SheetNameDataBaze).Controls(txt(i)).Value
Worksheets(SheetNameDataBaze).TextBox(txt(i)).Value
Worksheets(SheetNameDataBaze).OLEObjects(txt(i)).Value
Worksheets(SheetNameDataBaze).Shapes(txt(i)).Value
Worksheets(SheetNameDataBaze).txt(i).Value
```

nothing worked.

How should I define it?
It would be much easier then preparing the if statement for each TextBox.

Comment: Which textboxes do you have on your sheet? There are at least 2 options: ActiveX controls or *Insert* > *Text* > *Text Box*.

Comment: See [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15929058/excel-vba-cycle-through-listbox-controls) You can also use `TypeOf` in your loop

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that your textboxes on the worksheet are ActiveX controls and not forms controls.  If so, then does this work for you?

```
Sub ReferToTextboxes()


Dim txt As MSForms.TextBox
Dim o As OLEObject

For Each o In Sheet1.OLEObjects

If o.progID = "Forms.TextBox.1" Then

    Set txt = o.Object

    'now you can refer to txt and do what you need
    Debug.Print txt.Text

    End If

Next o

End Sub
```

Comment: also, if you want to refer directly to the textbox by using its name then use something like:     

 Dim txt As MSForms.TextBox
    
    Set txt = Sheet1.OLEObjects("txtCompany").Object

Answer (score 0):

I finally used:

```
Private Sub FunctionalProgramNew()

Dim bLoop As Double
Dim eLoop As Double
    bLoop = 8
    eLoop = 13

Dim txt(8 To 13) As String
    txt(8) = ("txtFuel_1")
    txt(9) = ("txtFuel_2")
    txt(10) = ("txtFuel_3")
    txt(11) = ("txtProduct_1")
    txt(12) = ("txtProduct_2")
    txt(13) = ("txtProduct_3")

Dim txtBox(8 To 13) As MSForms.TextBox
    For i = bLoop To eLoop
        Set txtBox(i) = Worksheets(SheetNameModel).OLEObjects(txt(i)).Object
    Next i


    For i = bLoop To eLoop
        If txtBox(i).Value <> CStr(Cells(ActiveCell.row, ActiveCell.Column + i - 2).Value) Then
            MsgBox ("Error code: " & txt(i))
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```